# sqlite - Insert data into blob

Tags: sql, shell, sqlite

I'm trying to insert binary data into a blob using SQLite3's shell, which means regular SQL statements. Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
    (ID INTEGER,
     BINDATA BLOB NOT NULL,
     SOMEFK INTEGER REFERENCES OTHERTABLE(ID) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

And this is the kind of insert statement I'm trying:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (BINDATA, SOMEFK)
VALUES (__READBINDATA('/tmp/somefile'), 1);
```

With `__READBINDATA(file)` being the function I am looking for. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in or shell function to read a file into a blob.

However, with the help of the [`hexdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump) tool, it's possible to transform a file's contents into a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

```sh
echo "insert into mytable(bindata, somefk) " \
     "values(x'"$(hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' /tmp/somefile)"', 1);"
```

This command can then be piped into the `sqlite3` shell.